# Assigning a char array to a char*

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that prefixes a string with its length. I can't seem to assign a char[] to a char *. Mysteriously, if I print out some debugging code before the assignment, it works.

```
char *prefixMsgWLength(char *msg){
  char *msgWLength;
  int msgLength = strlen(msg);

  if (msgLength == 0){
    msgWLength = "2|";
  }
  else{

    int nDigits = floor(log10(abs(msgLength))) + 1;
    int nDigits2 = floor(log10(abs(msgLength + nDigits + 1))) + 1;

    if (nDigits2 > nDigits){
      nDigits = nDigits2;
    }

    msgLength += nDigits + 1;

    char prefix[msgLength];
    sprintf(prefix, "%d|", msgLength);

    strcat(prefix, msg);
    // if I uncomment the below, msgWLength is returned correctly
    // printf("msg: %s\n", prefix);
    msgWLength = prefix;
  }
  return msgWLength;
}
```

Comment: prefix isn't big enough to hold the message and the length information. Try `char prefix[msgLength+11];` (11 being the size of the decimal representation of 2^32 plus one zero byte for string termination. Then return strdup(prefix);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is

```
 msgWLength = prefix;
```

here, you're assigning the address of a local variable (`prefix`) to the pointer and you try to `return` it.

Once the function finishes execution, the local variables will go out of scope and the returned pointer will be invalid.

You need to make `prefix` as a pointer and allocate memory dynamically, if you want it to retain it's *existence* after returning from the function.

Answer (score 0):

String reallocation to the exact length can be very cumbersome in C. You'd probably be much better off just using a sufficiently large buffer. Here, I use `limits.h` to determine the size of a line buffer according to the system (`LINE_MAX`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    /* Our message */
    char const msg[] = "Hello, world!";
    /* Buffer to hold the result */
    char buffer[LINE_MAX];

    /* Prefix msg with length */
    snprintf(buffer, LINE_MAX, "%lu|%s", strlen(msg)+1, msg);

    /* Print result */
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```